# How to search for special characters in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublime-text-3

I have a few lines starting with the character `#` and I search for it in SublimeText 3, but ST3 said `unable to find \b#\b`.

I then tried to search `\#` and it also fails (with regular expression mode enabled).

Other characters such as `& + -` have the same problem.

So how could I search for these special characters in ST3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text support searching by regex. http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html

You should be able to escape the character with a backslash. "#"

Comment: I disable the 'whole word' option then it works. The options seems to fail the RE as well.

Answer (score 3):

When searching for special characters switch off the regex .* to the left of find box.

[image: image of the find box with a red freehand circle around the ,*]

Comment: No, that is not true. You have to disable "Whole word" not regular expression. `#` is not a special character for regex.

Answer (score 0):

I had following text:

```
string + string
```

And i searched i wanted to replace empty space, plus and empty space with a new line. So my regular expression for searching was:

```
\s\+\s
```

And for replacing with new line just "\n"
I hope, i could help you.
For me, this worked.

[like on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIziS.png)